# Cocoapods podspec dependency import file not found

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, build, cocoapods

I'm trying to make a Cocoapod that depends on another but I'm having issues at compile time. Say in this case MyApp is using CocoapodA and CocoapodB, B relies on A.

MyApp Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '5.0'
pod 'CocoapodA'
pod 'CocoapodB', :path => '../../CocoapodB'
```

CocoapodB Podspec:

`s.dependency 'CocoapodA'`

but when I try to compile I get `'CocoapodA/CocoapodA.h' file not found` where the import in CocoapodB is trying to include it.

I've tried reading the Podspec documentation but I didn't really get what I'm missing. I also tried `s.library   = 'CocoapodA'`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you correctly specify header files for CocoapodA, for example:

`s.public_header_files = 'CocoapodA/**/*.h'`

Comment: CocoapodA is actually third party, you can see their podspec here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/OpenTokSDK-WebRTC/2.1.5/OpenTokSDK-WebRTC.podspec . The the problem is likely a problem with CocoapodB

Answer (score 0):

My problem ended up being that the OTHER_LDFLAGS were being overridden. After selecting the `Other Linker Flags` key (build settings) and pressing backspace it now builds.

Weirdly I can only build on actual device; both simulator and archive are failing. They're probably caused by something else.